# RAID 10 (2+2) and (4+4) - terminology or physical setup?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, storage, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

I understand what RAID10 (2+2) is (stripped mirror) whereby there are data are striped across 2 groups and each group have a pair of mirror devices (2 disks).

This is how i have understand "2+2"

For RAID10 4+4,  is it

1. striping across 4 groups, each group still having 2 mirrored
   devices or
2. striping across 2 groups, each group have 4 mirrored devices
3. striping across 4 groups, each group have 4 mirrored
   devices

2 and 3 just doesn't make sense.

How is 1) a 4+4 then ?

Regards,
Noob

Answer (score 0):

An 8 (4+4) disks RAID 10 setup is striped across 4 groups of 2-way mirrored device. In other words, it has *significantly higher performance* but *sligtly lower relibility* (due to increased disk count) than 4-disk RAID 10.